# Apply $\iint_S FdS$ where $F=(4x^3,e^{x^4}-y,z)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Apply divergence Gauss to find $\iint_S FdS$ where $F=(4x^3,e^{x^4}-y,z)$ and $ S$ is the portion of the paraboloid $z=x^2+y^2-6$ below $z=3$ oriented so that unit vector $\mathbf{n}\cdot(0,0,1)<0$. Hint: Remember $\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^2 xdx=\pi$.

I'm asked to solve this problem. I already computed div adding up the partial derivatives $$div(F)=12x^2 $$ So Now I have the Identity $$\iint_S F\cdot ndS = \iiint_B div(F)dV $$
But I'm not sure how to parametrize the region given to transform into $B$ (any help to continue?):

[image]

Comment: To parametrize $S$ use $(r,\varphi)\mapsto (r\cos(\varphi), r\sin(\varphi), r^2-6)$ for $r\in [0,3]$. If you don't use Stoke's theorem, you don't have to calculate curl of $F$.

Comment: Why did you calculate a curl? There was no curl in the surface integral in the problem, nor were you asked to compute a line integral that would necessitate using Stokes' theorem. This looks like a straightforward set up the surface integral and integrate, unless you would like to use Divergence theorem.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I'm asked to use divergence Gauss I thought It was necessary.

Comment: This seems like a weird problem for the divergence theorem, because you'll need to pick a solid and then subtract off the integrals along the other parts of the boundary to go that way. Are you sure you read the statement correctly?

Comment: @Ian Yes it says apply Gauss to find the integral $\iint_S FdS$. Could please bring some hints?

Comment: Divergence is simply $12x^2$. Find the volume integral and then find flux through disk at $z = 3$ and subtract.

Comment: Yeah I guess there's actually only one piece, I was looking too closely at your graph. So as Math Lover said, you can do the volume integral of the divergence. Since the flux you were asked for is already outward, you subtract the *outward* flux through the disk to get the downward flux through the paraboloid.

Comment: Good catch, I missed the -y.

Comment: @Valent given these hints, please make an attempt to solve and let us know if you get stuck

Comment: @MathLover how to get the $B$ volume region to integrate a triple integral?

Comment: At $z = 3, r = 3$ so integrate over this circle and $z$ is between $r^2 - 6$ and $3$

Comment: @MathLover $\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{0}^3\int_{r^2-6}^3 12x^3 dzdrd\theta $ ?

Comment: you missed Jacobian $r$. Also divergence is $12x^2$, write $x$ as $r \cos\theta$

Comment: @MathLover ok $\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{0}^3\int_{r^2-6}^3 12(r\cos\theta)^2\cdot r dzdrd\theta $

Comment: yes this is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the graph is not right. And the divergence should be
$$
\text{div}(F)=12x^2\,.
$$

The key problem of this question is that you can't find $B$ such that $S=\partial B$. However, you can add another boundary to make this happen.

Set $x=r\cos(\theta),y=r\sin(\theta),z=r^2-6$. Now, define the union of paraboloid and circle $C=\{(x,y,z)|x^2+y^2=9,\ z=3\}$:
$$
S'= S\cup \{(x,y,z)|x^2+y^2=9,\ z=3\}\,,
$$
where vector $n$ points outwards. Then
$$
\int\int_{S}F\cdot n\text{d}S=\int\int_{S'}F\cdot n\text{d}S'-\int\int_{C}F\cdot n\text{d}C=\int\int_{S'}F\cdot n\text{d}S'-27\pi.
$$
Denote
$$
B=\{(x,y,z)|x^2+y^2\leq z+6,\ -6\leq z\leq 3\}\,,
$$
then
$$
S'=\partial B\,.
$$
Then we use divergence theorem to calculate
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int\int_{S'}F\cdot n\text{d}S'&=\int\int\int_{B}\text{div}(F)\text{d}V
=\int^3_{-6}\int^{2\pi}_0\int^{\sqrt{z+6}}_012r^3\cos^2(\theta)\text{d}r\text{d}\theta\text{d}z\\
&=\int^3_{-6}\int^{2\pi}_0\int^{\sqrt{z+6}}_012r^3\cos^2(\theta)\text{d}r\text{d}\theta\text{d}z=\int^{3}_{-6}3(z+6)^{2}\text{d}z\int
^{2\pi}_0\cos^2(\theta)\text{d}\theta\\
&=9^3\times\pi=729\pi
\end{aligned}
$$
which implies
$$
\int\int_{S'}F\cdot n\text{d}S'=729\pi-27\pi=702\pi\,.
$$